# Check / Uncheck ListTiles in ListView.builder() - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView.builder();` in `showModalBottomSheet();`
Need to select / deselect multiple items on tap everything is well but need to close the modal and show it again to apply changes, another thing is the `ListTiles` sometimes duplicated more than once, function `emptyList` doesn't work well.

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'book_details.dart' show BookDetails;

    class Explore extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _ExploreState createState() => _ExploreState();
    }

    var _books,
        _categories,
        _arranges,
        _currentCategory,
        _selected,
        _primeColor,
        _currentFilter,
        _isThereIsFilters,
        _booksContainer,
        _booksWithFilters,
        _isLoading,
        _noBooks,
        _itemIcon;

    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKeyExplore =
        new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    List<String> _getCats = new List();
    List<String> _getArrs = new List();

    void _insertCategories() {
      for (int i = 0; i < _categories.length; i++) {
        _getCats.add(_categories[i]);
      }
      _getCats.sort();
    }

    void _insertArranges() {
      for (int i = 0; i < _arranges.length; i++) {
        _getArrs.add(_arranges[i]);
      }
    }

    class _ExploreState extends State<Explore> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

      onCatChange(String category) {
        setState(() {
          _currentCategory = category;
        });
      }

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _primeColor = Color.fromRGBO(239, 89, 39, 1.0);
        _categories = ["أول", "ثاني", "ثالث", "رابع", "خامس"];
        _arranges = ["أول", "ثاني", "ثالث", "رابع", "خامس"];
        _currentFilter = _arranges[0];
        _selected = [];
        _isThereIsFilters = false;
      }

      void emptyList(List list) {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          list.remove(list[i]);
        }
      }

      _showSheet(String type) {
        switch (type) {
          case "filters":
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: _scaffoldKeyExplore.currentContext,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Directionality(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    child: Container(
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: new ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: _getArrs[0] != null ? _getArrs.length : 0,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                              return new RadioListTile(
                                  title: Text(_getArrs[i]),
                                  value: _getArrs[i],
                                  groupValue: _currentFilter,
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _currentFilter = val;
                                    });
                                  });
                            }),
                      )
                    ])),
                  );
                });
            break;

          case "categories":
          default:
            showModalBottomSheet(
                context: _scaffoldKeyExplore.currentContext,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Directionality(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                    child: Container(
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            color: _primeColor,
                            child: Row(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        emptyList(_selected);
                                        //Navigator.pop(context);
                                        //_showSheet(type);
                                      }),
                                  IconButton(
                                      icon:
                                          Icon(Icons.done_all, color: Colors.white),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        if (_selected.length > 0) {
                                          _getFilteredBooks(_selected);
                                          setState(() {
                                            _isThereIsFilters = true;
                                          });
                                        } else {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _isThereIsFilters = false;
                                          });
                                        }
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      })
                                ]),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: new ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: _getCats != null ? _getCats.length : 0,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                                  final _isSelected = _selected.contains(_getCats[i]);
                                  return new ListTile(
                                      leading: Icon(Icons.category),
                                      trailing: _isSelected ? Icon(Icons.done) : null,
                                      title: Text(_getCats[i]),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          _isSelected
                                              ? _selected.remove(_getCats[i])
                                              : _selected.add(_getCats[i]);
                                        });
                                        //Navigator.pop(context);
                                        //_showSheet(type);
                                      });
                                }),
                          )
                        ])),
                  );
                });
            break;
        }
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: new Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKeyExplore,
              appBar:
                  AppBar(title: Text("استكشاف"), elevation: 0.0, actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.category, color: _primeColor),
                    onPressed: () => _showSheet("categories")),
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list, color: _primeColor),
                    onPressed: () => _showSheet("filters"))
              ]),
              body: Center(child: Text("Nothing..."));
            ));
      }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to close the modal and show it again to apply changes

This happens because the `showModalBottomSheet`'s `builder` needs to be called again to reflect the changes.
In Flutter, `StatefulWidget`s should be able to rebuild any time the state changes - which is not the case here, because of the bottom sheet being shown.

**Why did I run into this issue (on a meta level)?**

Storing the state in `StatefulWidget`s is useful for saving UI state, but you quickly outgrow this technique if you want to store some "app state" or "data state" that is independent of the screen it's on.

It is finally time to *fundamentally rethink your state management* and settle on a full-fledged state management pattern that decouples the state from the widgets. Luckily, there are a few to choose from:

- **Making everything global**, like you did above. **This is generally not a good idea**, as you break the contract of `setState` (state can be modified without the widgets being notified). Also, you break hot restart and stuff like that.
- Using an **`InheritedWidget`**, where widgets below a root widget can access the same state.
- Using a **`ScopedModel`**, which builds on top of that.
- Using the infamous **BLoC pattern**, which also builds on top of the `InheritedWidget`, but adds some `Stream`-y stuff to make everything more reactive.
- Probably many more.

Here is a great [Youtube video about state management from Google I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI), where several patterns are being presented.

**Anyways, are bottom sheets the right widget for the task ahead?**

According to [the Material Design spec](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#usage), the modal bottom sheet is "an alternative to inline menus or simple dialogs on mobile, providing room for additional items, longer descriptions, and iconography".

More concrete, the `showModalBottomSheet` function is designed to show a widget that doesn't affect the parent over time, but rather - if at all - at a single point in time. That's why it returns a `Future<T>`, not a `Stream<T>`.

Be aware that you are trying to use the bottom sheet in a way that it's not intended to be used.
In your case, I'd recommend just using a new screen.

Comment: Nice words, thank you very much. Is there any alternative to my idea?

Comment: Sorry, after doing some more research and a lot of thinking, I realized it's a general state problem (not only of the bottom sheet). I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem, I used a new screen. Thanks for your time.